# How to get id of just-executed sql query (in php)

Tags: php, sql

In php I have an INSERT query to database. This query add some issue to database. I want to check if issue was added fine (there are some cases when issue doesn't added - without any mistake reporting). How to check this?

I have an idea, that after i make INSERT query i should make a query, for example: `SELECT ..... WHERE id=last_id`. But how to get the last_id - how to get id of last INSERT query? (id is autoincrementing sql field)

Thank you

Comment: Which database (MySQL / SQL / PostgreSQL / SQLite / etc.)? And what functions are you using?

Comment: What do use you for executing the query? `mysql`, `pdo`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - INSERT and catch the id auto-increment value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621369/sql-insert-and-catch-the-id-auto-increment-value)

Comment: Postgresql, connecting via PEAR MDB2

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I've found and answer in that topic. Sorry for duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the answer to this StackOverflow question useful:

[SQL - INSERT and catch the id auto-increment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621369/sql-insert-and-catch-the-id-auto-increment-value)

Comment: Thank you. 
Sorry for duplicate question. I've used search but it was uneffective.
I found answer there

Answer (score 5):

[mysql_insert_id();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

More info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 1):

mysql_insert_id function returns id of previously inserted record.

I assume you're working with MySQL