# Split tags and submit them to database

Tags: php, javascript, sql, database, tags

I am trying to create a javascript that split the tags (that the user gives, separated them with comma (,)) and pass them in my database in different rows but with the same id.
i have this code:

```
<form name="formatform" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_format_form()" action="formatsubmit.php">
<p>
Συντομος Τιτλος:<input type="text" name="titlos" value="">
Συντομη περιγραφη:<input type="text" name="perigrafi" value="">
</p>
<p>
Τοποθεσια:<input type="text" id="loc" name="topothesia" value="">
Tags:<input type="text" name="tags" value="">
**Οι ετικέτες πρέπει να χωρίζονται με κόμμα
</p>
.
.
.
</form>
```

and in formatsubmit.php which is the one who pass them into database these code:

```
$query= " INSERT into photos(`title`,`description`,`location`,`privilages`,`ph_tags`) VALUES ('".$_POST['titlos']."','".$_POST['perigrafi']."','".$_POST['topothesia']."','".$_POST['radio_check']."','".$_POST['tags']."') ";
$result= mysql_query($query,$con);
```

If the user gives 3 tags(separated with comma) i want to split them and pass them to database in different rows. 
How can i do that?

Comment: What is your schema like?  Surely you have a table called `tags`

Comment: i have a table photos with a column tags and a table tags that is connected with the table photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting the tag input into an array using comma as the delimiter and then iterating over the tags and creating one insert statement per tag? E.g.

```
$tag_array = explode(",", $_POST['tags']);
foreach ($tag_array as $tag) {
  $query= " INSERT into photos(`title`,`description`,`location`,`privilages`,`ph_tags`) VALUES ('".$_POST['titlos']."','".$_POST['perigrafi']."','".$_POST['topothesia']."','".$_POST['radio_check']."','".$tag."') ";
  $result= mysql_query($query,$con);
}
```

Comment: it works but i also have a problem. this is about a photo.i'm uploading a photo, and i give a title,a description,tags etc for the photo. i want to pass them to my database but using the id (auto increment in database) that code gives me 3 rows(if i had 3 tags) with different ids..but i want to have the same id for that 3 rows :S how can i have this done..??

Comment: @user1385257 Create a separate table for tags, referencing the photo table. E.g. first insert the photo row, retrieve the newly created id and then insert one row per tag using the photo id.

Comment: i've already have a table tags which is referencing to the photo table. nice thought. thanks a lot..!!

Comment: can you give me an example code for this "first insert the photo row, retrieve the newly created id and then insert one row per tag using the photo id"??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621369/sql-insert-and-catch-the-id-auto-increment-value on how to retrieve the auto-incremented id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHP, use `explode(",", $input);`. To do it in JavaScript, do `input=input.split(",")`. You will then have an array of tags that you can reference by number (e.g. `$input[0]...$input[x]` (PHP) or `input[0]...input[x]` (JavaScript)).

Comment: i prefer to do it with a function in javascript. i'll try it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should also process the user input as you will get users that enter double tags `,,` making explode have empty values plus using `POST` like that you will have sql injections:

```
<?php 
function get_tags($tags){
    $ret=array();
    $tags=explode(',',strtolower($tags));
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        if($tag==''){}else{
            $ret[]=ucfirst(trim($tag));
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function insert_photo_tags($tags){
    array_walk($_POST,'mysql_real_escape_string');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $query = " INSERT INTO photos(`title`,`description`,`location`,`privilages`,`ph_tags`) 
                   VALUES ('".$_POST['titlos']."','".$_POST['perigrafi']."','".$_POST['topothesia']."','".$_POST['radio_check']."','".$tag."') ";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}

//Test Input (?tags=php,mySQL,http,bLa,,,,,,123)

$tags = get_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tags']));

//Do your insert with the array
insert_photo_tags($tags);

print_r($tags);
/*
Array
(
[0] => Php
[1] => Mysql
[2] => Http
[3] => Bla
[4] => 123
)
*/
?>
```