# Inserting mysql foreign keys and primary keys in a transaction.

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Just looking for some tips and pointers for a small project I am doing. I have some ideas but I am not sure if they are the best practice. I am using mysql and php.

I have a table called nomsing in the database.

It has a primary key called row id which is an integer.

Then I have about 8 other tables referencing this table. 
That are called nomplu, accsing,accplu, datsing, datplu for instance.
Each has a column that references the primary key of nomsing.

Withing my php code I have all the information to insert into the tables except one thing , the row id primary key of the nomsing table. So that php generates a series of inserts like the following.

```
INSERT INTO nomsing(word,postress,gender) VALUES (''велосипед","8","mask").
INSERT INTO nomplu(word,postress,NOMSING?REFERENCE) VALUES (''велосипеды","2",@the reference to the id of the first insert@).
```

There are more inserts but this one gets the point across. The second insert should reference the auto generated id for the first insert. I was this to work as a transaction so all inserts should complete or none.

One idea I have is to not auto generate the id and generate it myself in php. That way would know the id given before the transaction but then I would have to check if the id was already in the db.

Another idea I have is to do the first insert and then query for the row id of that insert in php and then make the second insert. I mean both should work but they don't seem like an optimal solution. I am not too familiar with the database transactional features but what would be the best approach to do in this case. I don't like the idea of inserting then querying for the id and then running the rest of the queries. Just seems very inefficient or perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621369/sql-insert-and-catch-the-id-auto-increment-value

Comment: in transactions `new.PK_field_name_in_inserted_table` will return last inserted id for current session. So you can use it in manually created transactions. I don't know if it's what you want but hope it helps. By the way, there's syntax error in your queries.

Comment: That looks very good. Thank you. Do you know if this mysql_insert_id function is thread safe. I mean if one user calls the insert and then another at a split second later. Then when the first user calls the get ID it gets the id of the insert from the second user.

Comment: Yes the queries are just dummy queries to explain the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert a row in the master table. Then you can fetch the [insert id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) ( [lastInserId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) when on PDO)  and use that to populate your other queries.

Comment: I am a bit of a noob. What is PDO?

Comment: On PHP there are 3 common way's to access MySQL data: mysql (deprecated) mysqli and PDO. PDO is the your favorite choice for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the php version as given by JvdBerg , or Mysql's [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). I usually use the former option.

See a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new column to the `nomsing` table, called 'insert_order' (or similar) with a default value of 0, then instead of generating one SQL statement per insert create a bulk insert statement e.g.

```
INSERT INTO nomsing(word,postress,gender, insert_order) 
VALUES (''велосипед","8","mask",1), (''abcd'',"9","hat",2).....
```

you generate the `insert_order` number with a counter in your loop starting at one. Then you can perform one `SELECT` on the table to get the ids e.g.

```
SELECT row_id
FROM   nomsing
WHERE  insert_order > 0;
```

now you have all the IDs you can now do a bulk insert for your following queries. At the end of your script just do an update to reset the `insert_order` column back to 0

```
UPDATE nomsing SET insert_order = 0 WHERE insert_order > 0;
```

It may seem messy to add an extra column to do this but it will add a significant speed increase over performing one query at a time.